# How to set the tax for each line entry in the Quickbook Invoice using python quickbooks?

Tags: python, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am creating the invoice using `python-quickbooks`. I am creating multiple line-entries in the using the following code:

```
        #------------------------------------------------------
        #   Line Details
        #------------------------------------------------------

        line_detail = SalesItemLineDetail()
        line_detail.UnitPrice = 100  # in dollars
        line_detail.Qty = 1  # quantity can be decimal
        line_detail.ServiceDate = "2020-03-18"
       
        item_ref = Ref()
        item_ref.value = "1"
        item_ref.name = "Services"
        
        line = SalesItemLine()
        line.Amount = 100  # in dollars
        line.Description = "Line Entry Description"
        line.SalesItemLineDetail = line_detail
        line.SalesItemLineDetail.ItemRef = item_ref
```

However, I would to enable tax for each of the line entries and set the overall tax as "Federal Tax" at 12%

Any idea how to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since your bounty states you are looking for an answer from a reputable source, I thought I'd give sources and the specific example you asked for.

## Using default QuickBooks Rates

Applying the default Federal Tax is straigthforward. [This](https://github.com/ej2/python-quickbooks/issues/112) issue on the `python-quickbooks` GitHub shows how:

```
line_detail.TaxRef = Ref()
line_detail.TaxRef.value = #TAX CODE HERE#
```

> You will need to use the correct Tax Reference code for your country/region.

The only allowed values for the USA are "TAX" for standard sales tax or "NON" for no tax.

i.e.:

Sales tax for USA would be done like this:

```
line_detail.TaxRef = Ref()
line_detail.TaxRef.value = "TAX"
```

If you want no tax for an item:

```
line_detail.TaxRef = Ref()
line_detail.TaxRef.value = "NON"
```

## Specifying a tax rate yourself

You can find more details about TaxCodes in Intuit's API Reference [here](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/taxcode).

You can find details about how the actual tax calculations are made at [Manage sales tax for US locales](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/tutorials/manage-sales-tax-for-us-locales).

The gist of it is that the ref tag is first checked, with the only valid values being `"TAX"` and `"NON"`. The associated TaxService will use those codes to calculate the actual tax. You can create more codes that apply specific rates you specify yourself using   [TaxService](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/taxservice).

To create your own `TaxCode` that is `"Federal Tax"` at a rate of `12%`, you would do this:

```
from quickbooks.objects.taxservice import TaxService, TaxRateDetails

taxservice = TaxService()
taxservice.TaxCode = "Federal Tax"

tax_rate_detail = TaxRateDetails()
tax_rate_detail.TaxRateName = "Federal Tax"
tax_rate_detail.RateValue = 12
tax_rate_detail.TaxAgencyId = 1
tax_rate_detail.TaxApplicableOn = "Sales"   

taxservice.TaxRateDetails.append(tax_rate_detail)
created_taxservice = taxservice.save(qb=handle_to_your_quickbooks_client)
```

Comment: How can I update or delete tax service if needed

Comment: TaxService can't be updated or deleted using python-quickbooks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your Problem correctly I would say adding tax to SalesItem's can be done with the follwing code.

```
line_detail.TaxRef = Ref()
line_detail.TaxRef.value = "YOUR COUTRY TAX CODE"
```

This should also set the correct standard/overall tax from the supplied tax code.